# Autofac two pgsql database connections

Tags: c#, .net-core, autofac

We are using `InstancePerLifetimeScope` for Database . But in some case we need a new db connection. 
Our autofac registration is

```
builder.RegisterType<Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection> ()
     As<IDbConnection> ()
     .WithParameter ("connectionString", constr)
     .InstancePerLifetimeScope ();

 // for NewDb Connection     
 builder.RegisterType<Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection> ()
      .As<IDpNewDb> ()
      .WithParameter ("connectionString", constr)
      .InstancePerRequest ();
```

Code for IDpNewDb is

`public interface IDpNewDb : IDbConnection { }`

We are getting a error while running this code

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code: 'The type
>   'Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection' is not assignable to service
>   'xxxx.Core.Data.IDpNewDb'.'

Any idea ?

**Edit** : Below the code for a cut-down version of the app

My Startup Class

```
public class Startup {
    public Startup (IConfiguration configuration) {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {
        services.AddMvc ().SetCompatibilityVersion (CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        ConfigureAutofac (services);
    }
    internal static AutofacServiceProvider ConfigureAutofac (IServiceCollection services) {

        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder ();

        containerBuilder.RegisterModule<DefaultModule> ();
        containerBuilder.Populate (services);
        var container = containerBuilder.Build ();
        var srv = new AutofacServiceProvider (container);
        return srv;
    }
    public void Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment ()) {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage ();
        } else {
            app.UseHsts ();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection ();
        app.UseMvc ();
    }
}
```

Autofac Module

```
 internal class DefaultModule : Autofac.Module {
        public void init (ContainerBuilder builder) {
            Load (builder);
        }

        protected override void Load (ContainerBuilder builder) {
            builder.RegisterType<Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection> ()
                .As<IDbConnection> ()
                .WithParameter ("connectionString", "Server=localhost;Database=DBName;User Id=postgres;password=*******;Application Name=myapp;")
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope ();

            builder.RegisterType<Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection> ()
                .As<IDbNewDb> ()
                .WithParameter ("connectionString", "Server=localhost;Database=DBName;User Id=postgres;password=******;Application Name=myapp;")
                .InstancePerRequest ();
        }

    }
```

**interfaces.cs**

```
namespace autofac_issue {
        public interface IDbNewDb : IDbConnection { };
}
```

Finally, Controller

```
namespace autofac_issue.Controllers {
    [Route ("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase {
        // GET api/values
        public ValuesController (IDbNewDb dbnew, IDbConnection db) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the definition of NpgsqlConnection?

Comment: `Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection` is the postgresql provider for .net https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.html

Comment: Where exactly is IDpNewDb defined? Is that custom? What is IDbConnection? Pretend we don't know anything about your app... Because we don't. (Update the content of the question with all this, not just comments down here...)

Comment: @TravisIllig Thanks for the support . I just created a sample app and updated the post accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line won't work

```
 builder.RegisterType<Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection> ()
        .As<IDpNewDb> ()
```

`NpgsqlConnection` does not implement `IDpNewDb`. You will have a similar error even using pure C#.

If you want a new instance of `IDbConnection` you can use `Owned` combined with `Func<>` which will act like a mini scope and you will have a new instance whenever you want.

```
public class X {
    public X(Func<Owned<IDbConnection>> dbConnectionFactory){
        this._dbConnectionFactory = dbConnectionFactory;
    }

    private readonly Func<Owned<IDbConnection>> _dbConnectionFactory; 

    public void Do(){
        // will create a new instance each time you call the factory 
        using(Owned<IDbConnection> ownedDbConnection = this._dbConnectionFactory()){
            IDbConnection dbConnection = ownedDbConnection.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

See [Combining `Owned` with `Func`](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/owned-instances.html#combining-owned-with-func) from the Autofac documentation for more information.